# SonarQube always exclude swift files

Tags: swift, xcode, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to implement SonarQube in my iOS project. I'm doing it on an M2 Macbook Pro running Ventura 13.2.1 and Xcode 14.3.1. I am using SonarScanner to help do it. I have tried creating the coverage report manually using Slather and it can actually work and show the code coverage. However I can't seem to send it to SonarQube dashboard. It always shows the message `"The main branch has no lines of code."` This is the `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
#
# Swift SonarQube Plugin - Enables analysis of Swift and Objective-C projects into SonarQube.
# Copyright © 2015 Backelite (${email})
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#

# Sonar Server details
sonar.host.url=http://43.218.84.199:9000
sonar.login=xxxxxx
sonar.password=yyyyyyy

# Project Details
sonar.projectKey=bimb-bia-ios
sonar.projectName=BIMB Authenticator for iOS
sonar.projectDescription=This is the Sonar for BIMB Authenticator iOS

# Comment if you have a project with mixed ObjC / Swift
sonar.language=swift

# Path to source directories
# sonar.sources=SonarDemo,SonarDemoTests,SonarDemoUITests
sonar.sources=bimb-authenticate-ios
sonar.tests=bimb-authenticate-iosTests

# Exclude directories
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/**
sonar.inclusions=**/*.swift
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,Pods/**/*,Reports/**/*,Talsec/**/*,**/Swinject/**

# Path to test directories (comment if no test)
sonar.tests=bimb-authenticate-iosTests,bimb-authenticate-iosUITests

# Destination Simulator to run surefire
# As string expected in destination argument of xcodebuild command
# Example = sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.2
# sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=12.0
sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro,OS=16.4

# Xcode project configuration (.xcodeproj)
# and use the later to specify which project(s) to include in the analysis (comma separated list)
# Specify either xcodeproj or xcodeproj + xcworkspace
sonar.swift.project=bimb-authenticate-ios.xcodeproj
sonar.swift.workspace=bimb-authenticate-ios.xcworkspace

# Specify your appname.
# This will be something like "myApp"
# Use when basename is different from targeted scheme. 
# Or when slather fails with 'No product binary found'
sonar.swift.appName=bimb-authenticate-ios

# Scheme to build your application
sonar.swift.appScheme=bimb-authenticate-ios

# Configuration to use for your scheme. if you do not specify that the default will be Debug
sonar.swift.appConfiguration=Debug

##########################
# Optional configuration #
##########################

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# SCM
# sonar.scm.enabled=true
# sonar.scm.url=scm:git:http://xxx

# JUnit report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/TEST-report.xml
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
# The XML files have to be prefixed by TEST- otherwise they are not processed
sonar.junit.reportsPath=sonar-reports/TEST-report.xml

# Cobertura report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/coverage-swift.xml
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
sonar.swift.coverage.reportPattern=sonar-reports/coverage-swift*.xml
#sonar.swift.coverage.reportPattern=sonar-reports/cobertura.xml

# OCLint report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/oclint.xml
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
sonar.swift.swiftlint.report=sonar-reports/*swiftlint.txt

# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
sonar.swift.tailor.report=sonar-reports/*tailor.txt

# Paths to exclude from coverage report (surefire, 3rd party libraries etc.)
# sonar.swift.excludedPathsFromCoverage=pattern1,pattern2
# sonar.swift.excludedPathsFromCoverage=.*Tests.*,

##########################
# Tailor configuration #
##########################
# Tailor configuration
# -l,--max-line-length=<0-999>                  maximum Line length (in characters)
#    --list-files                               display Swift source files to be analyzed
#    --max-class-length=<0-999>                 maximum Class length (in lines)
#    --max-closure-length=<0-999>               maximum Closure length (in lines)
#    --max-file-length=<0-999>                  maximum File length (in lines)
#    --max-function-length=<0-999>              maximum Function length (in lines)
#    --max-name-length=<0-999>                  maximum Identifier name length (in characters)
#    --max-severity=<error|warning (default)>   maximum severity
#    --max-struct-length=<0-999>                maximum Struct length (in lines)
#    --min-name-length=<1-999>                  minimum Identifier name length (in characters)

sonar.swift.tailor.config=--no-color --max-line-length=100 --max-file-length=500 --max-name-length=40 --max-name-length=40 --min-name-length=4
```

This is the verbose log from Sonar:

```
[21:18:50]: ▸ INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sonar-scanner/5.0.1.3006/libexec/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
[21:18:50]: ▸ INFO: Project root configuration file: /Users/bawenang/Documents/bimb-auth-ios/authenticator-ios-app/sonar-project.properties
[21:18:50]: ▸ INFO: SonarScanner 5.0.1.3006
[21:18:50]: ▸ INFO: Java 21.0.1 Homebrew (64-bit)
[21:18:50]: ▸ INFO: Mac OS X 13.2.1 aarch64
[21:18:50]: ▸ INFO: User cache: /Users/bawenang/.sonar/cache
[21:18:50]: ▸ INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 10.2.1.78527
[21:18:50]: ▸ INFO: Default locale: "en_ID", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[21:18:51]: ▸ INFO: Load global settings
[21:18:51]: ▸ INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=562ms
[21:18:51]: ▸ INFO: Server id: 243B8A4D-AYtqBBf16o1Yqf4ORLpb
[21:18:51]: ▸ INFO: User cache: /Users/bawenang/.sonar/cache
[21:18:51]: ▸ INFO: Load/download plugins
[21:18:51]: ▸ INFO: Load plugins index
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=223ms
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=301ms
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Process project properties
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=4ms
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Execute project builders
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Project key: bimb-bia-ios
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Base dir: /Users/bawenang/Documents/bimb-auth-ios/authenticator-ios-app
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Working dir: /Users/bawenang/Documents/bimb-auth-ios/authenticator-ios-app/.scannerwork
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'bimb-bia-ios'
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'bimb-bia-ios' (done) | time=335ms
[21:18:52]: ▸ INFO: Load quality profiles
[21:18:53]: ▸ INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=251ms
[21:18:53]: ▸ INFO: Load active rules
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=7322ms
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO: Load analysis cache
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO: Load analysis cache (404) | time=172ms
[21:19:00]: ▸ WARN: The properties 'sonar.login' and 'sonar.password' are deprecated and will be removed in the future. Please pass a token with the 'sonar.token' property instead.
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO: Load project repositories
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=173ms
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO: Indexing files...
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO: Project configuration:
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO:   Included sources: **/*.swift
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO:   Excluded sources: **/*.xml, Pods/**/*, Reports/**/*, Talsec/**/*, **/Swinject/**, **/*Test*/**, **/*.swift
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO:   Included tests: **/*Test*/**
[21:19:01]: ▸ INFO: 10 files indexed
[21:19:01]: ▸ INFO: 254 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
[21:19:01]: ▸ INFO: 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
[21:19:01]: ▸ INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module BIMB Authenticator for iOS
[21:19:01]: ▸ INFO: Load metrics repository
[21:19:01]: ▸ INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=225ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=1ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [javascript]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: No CSS, PHP, HTML or VueJS files are found in the project. CSS analysis is skipped.
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [javascript] (done) | time=0ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor C# Project Type Information [csharp]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor C# Project Type Information [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor C# Analysis Log [csharp]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor C# Analysis Log [csharp] (done) | time=8ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor TextAndSecretsSensor [text]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor TextAndSecretsSensor [text] (done) | time=188ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet] (done) | time=0ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor VB.NET Analysis Log [vbnet]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor VB.NET Analysis Log [vbnet] (done) | time=13ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet] (done) | time=0ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor IaC Docker Sensor [iac]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor IaC Docker Sensor [iac] (done) | time=40ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor Analysis Warnings import [csharp]
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor Analysis Warnings import [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=0ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 0 files
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=0ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Analysis report generated in 40ms, dir size=136.9 kB
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Analysis report compressed in 9ms, zip size=16.3 kB
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 255ms
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can find the results at: http://43.218.84.199:9000/dashboard?id=bimb-bia-ios
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: More about the report processing at http://43.218.84.199:9000/api/ce/task?id=AYu0c2MfoXOXg-m1xLOA
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Analysis total time: 10.675 s
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Total time: 12.161s
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: Final Memory: 21M/80M
[21:19:02]: ▸ INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From the log, I saw that there is somehting peculiar here:

```
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO: Project configuration:
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO:   Included sources: **/*.swift
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO:   Excluded sources: **/*.xml, Pods/**/*, Reports/**/*, Talsec/**/*, **/Swinject/**, **/*Test*/**, **/*.swift
[21:19:00]: ▸ INFO:   Included tests: **/*Test*/**
[21:19:01]: ▸ INFO: 10 files indexed
[21:19:01]: ▸ INFO: 254 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
[21:19:01]: ▸ INFO: 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
```

As you can see, I'm not sure why but `**/*Test*/**` and `**/*.swift` are excluded even though I cannot see them in the exclusions. Can you guys help me?

Thanks.